# ajax send data but php says undefinded index

Tags: php, ajax

**PHP FILE:**

```
   <?php
    $result = $_POST['ID'];
    echo($result);    
   ?>
```

**AJAX FILE**

```
$('.P0').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'wishlist.php',
        data : 'ID=' +  pid[0],
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(ar){
        alert(ar);  
        }
    });
window.location = "http://localhost/FashionWorld/PAGES/wishlist.php";
});
```

I also tried `json_encode()` and other methods and also tried without dataType
but nothing works..

My PHP version is 7.1

Please help...

Comment: You're passing your data wrong. `data: {ID: pid[0]},` though I'm not sure where your `pid[0]` is from and it would still result in undefined as I cannot see it in your current post.

Comment: Declaring the value of `data` as `data : 'ID=' +  pid[0]` is wrong syntax. `data` attribute expects a JSON object. Hence it should be corrected as `data : {ID:pid[0]}`..

Comment: hungrykoala sir, i tried with data : {ID: 10} but no effect..

Comment: That should be `data: {ID: "10"}` values should be enclosed in `""` while variables shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code like below

```
$('.P0').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'wishlist.php',
    data : {
        ID:pid[0],              // Change the data passing to this.
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(ar){
    alert(ar);  
    }
});
window.location = "http://localhost/FashionWorld/PAGES/wishlist.php";
});
```

The way you passed the data was wrong.
Try above modification and check if it works.

Comment: Not working...success function response correct value but php undefined index ID error

Comment: Try sending without `dataType: 'json'` and see if it works. Also, let us know how you are getting pid[0].

Answer (score 0):

When the **dataType** is set to **JSON** you need to send data in **JSON** Format

Updated Code:

```
$('.P0').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
     type : 'post',
     url : 'wishlist.php',
     data : {"ID": pid[0]},
     dataType : 'json',
     success : function(ar){
        alert(ar);  
     }
  });
 window.location = "http://localhost/FashionWorld/PAGES/wishlist.php";
```

});

On your PHP file you can read this Value using global `$_POST` Variable

Comment: Not working..but success function response correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in the variable:

```
data : 'ID=' +  pid[0]
```

I suggest you to test first by a initialized value E.g.

```
data : 'ID=1'
```

Second Example:

```
    <input id='record_id' value='2'/>

<button class='PO'>Send<button>

<script>
var record_id= $('#record_id').val();
$('.P0').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'wishlist.php',
        data : 'ID=' + record_id,
        success : function(ar){
        alert(ar);  
        }
    });
window.location = "http://localhost/FashionWorld/PAGES/wishlist.php";
});

</script>
```

Comment: tried but Notice: Undefined index: ID in G:\wamp64\www\FashionWorld\PAGES\wishlist.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.. i added json.parse

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'wishlist.php',
        data : 'ID=' +  pid[0],
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(ar){
        var xxx = JSON.parse(ar);
        alert(xxx);  
        }
    });
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: ID in G:\wamp64\www\FashionWorld\PAGES\wishlist.php on line 2

Comment: how did you pass variable "ID"

Answer (score -2):

There are various ways to do it , here is one :-

```
<script>
$("'.P0").on('click', function(){
        var xmlhttp ;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
        else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","wishlist.php?ID="+pid[0],true); //Define array pid[] in some other place
        xmlhttp.send(); 
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                var result = xmlhttp.responseText ;                     
                alert(result) ;
            }
        }           
    });     
});
</script>
```

Hope this will work .

Comment: Question is posted as jQuery yet you posted a DOM answer. OP is also using POST and yet you posted GET.

Comment: The above one should work , only reason can be the pid variable , set it properly .